# How to pass to package unicode-math's \setmathfont command a path to a font file?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, luatex, unicode-math, paths

I downloaded the OpenType font file `STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf` from the [STIX Two Git repository](https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/tree/master/fonts/static_otf), and saved it as `~/STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf`.

I then saved the following LaTeX code in the file `~/Hw2/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{../STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I then executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~/Hw2
> lualatex Test
```

The compilation failed, and the following message appeared in `~/Hw2/Test.log`.

```
Package fontspec Info: Font family '../STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf(0)' created for
(fontspec)             font '../STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCap
sFont={},Script=Math,FontAdjustment={\__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens:
(fontspec)             }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[../STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf]:mode=base;script=math;l
anguage=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens: 

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TU+.. on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file TU...fd. on input line 6.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/../STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf(0)/m' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 6.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
n
l.6 \begin
        {document}
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
n
l.6 \begin
        {document}
End of file on the terminal!
```

---

**Questions**

1. Why did the compilation fail?
2. How can I pass to the `\setmathfont` command the path to the `STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf` font file?

---

**Further Considerations**

If instead of `../STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf` I write `STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf`, the compilation completes successfully, but I imagine this is due to one of the following reasons:

1. Either `STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf` is part of the TeXLive installation or of my operating system's fonts catalog, and the `lualatex` engine finds this font file in the canonical folders associated with TeXLive fonts or with my operating system's fonts,
2. or the `\setmathfont` has some built-in method of looking for font files, which includes looking for them in the active directory's parent directory.

In either case, I would appreciate a general answer to my question, that will be able to deal with

1. `.otf` files that have not previously been saved in my file system,
2. and paths that `\setmathfont` doesn't search automatically.

Comment: see the PATH option described in the  fontspec documentation.

Comment: run `texdoc fontspec`  in a terminal

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. I didn't realize the `\setmathfont` command belongs to the `fontspec` package.

Comment: stix two is part of texlive and mikex, why are you installing it by hand in a non standard place?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Firstly, I didn't know it was part of TeXLive. Secondly, what if in the future (possibly the very near future) I will want to use a math font other than STIX Two, one that is not part of the TeXLive installation?

Comment: just install any otf fonts you find in your OS eg on windows drop into the windows\fonts directory. Using paths in the document  makes the document non portable and may be useful as a quick fix but can not be recommended

Comment: \setmathfont belongs to unicode-math, but unicode-math makes use of fontspec to load the fonts. But I quite agree with David: I use Path only very rarely, all normal fonts are either installed in my system or in a texmf tree in the proper location.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my opinion relying on a font to be installed in the OS or as part of the local TeX system installation is less portable than saving it inside the project's directory tree and hard-coding its relative path.

Comment: @EvanAad for large opentype fonts with tens of thousands of characters you really do not want a copy of the font with every document. Fonts already make up the largest part of texlive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-OS-system-installed fonts may be referred to in various ways: in texmf tree or current folder, Path= not required; elsewhere, Path= required.

[image: path]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchUppercase}
\setmathfont[Scale=0.97]{STIX Two Math}
\setmainfont[Scale=0.97]{STIX Two Text}


\setmathfontface{\texthiero}[
Path=C:/[long local path]/fonts/3/f/,
Extension=.otf,
]{Aegyptus} 
\setmathfontface{\textcurr}[Scale=2]{Maya.otf} 
\newfontface{\ttextcurr}[Scale=2,Colour=red]{Maya.otf} 

\begin{document}

texmf-tree font (log = .../texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype
/public/stix2-otf/STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf):

\[ x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}\]

Path= font (C:/.../.../.../fonts/3/f/):

{\Large
\[ \texthiero{}(\texthiero{}+\texthiero{}=\texthiero{}\texthiero{}) \]
}

Current folder font {\ttextcurr{\symbol{97}}\ttextcurr{\symbol{98}}\ttextcurr{\symbol{99}}}:

{\Large
\[ \textcurr{\char97} + \textcurr{\char98} = \textcurr{\char99} \]
}

\end{document}
```